# Platform dependent .war-file produced with maven and Jersey/Jackson setting?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey, jackson

I am trying to write a little REST service as a Java todolist application.
Fortunately it runs on tomcat in my Windows 10 environment.
Unfortunately it refuses to run on tomcat in my Linux environment (see details below).
I thought the idea of Java is to be platform independant.
Where is the catch? What am I doing wrong?

### Details of environments

#### *Works* on Windows 10 Pro

- apache tomcat 8.5.4
- jvm 1.8.0_101-b13
- architecture amd64

#### *Fails* on Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (4.4.0-34-generic) (in virtualbox)

- apache tomcat 8.5.4
- jvm 1.8.0_101-b13
- with architecture amd64

Here are the links to my files. I am sorry for not being able to post it here as marked code (markdown or html). I gave up after 45 Minutes. What a shame. :(

**[Exception report](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9e8oszhmb1hx2yn/exceptionReport.txt?dl=0)**

```
type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet todolist threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet todolist threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:331)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.5.4 logs.
```

**[pom.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l1obc8vey1jdtlg/pom.xml?dl=0)**

```xml
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.mathema.hc2016.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>todolist</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TODO List Service</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>todolist</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[JSONService.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z8qewfat9b3klkn/JSONService.java?dl=0)

[TaskSet.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpa0vtkifss9imr/TaskSet.java?dl=0)

[Task.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j72dcpiuomme7n7/Task.java?dl=0)

[web.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l32d4c40glsoldw/web.xml?dl=0)

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: could not access the Exception report. Can you tell me what's the error?

Comment: You're including [`jersey-container-servlet:2.23.1`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet) from June 2016, but mixing that with `jersey-json:1.8` from June 2011, when [`jersey-json:1.19.1`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json) from March 2016 exists. I think your code is out of sync, though I don't know why it worked on Windows. Suggest you try upgrading the compatible version of `jersey-json` and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis and thoughts. I even tried jersey-json:1.19.2 today but did not succeed. I will try this again and report the error message here.

Comment: jersey-json:1.19.1: works on Windows, does **not** work on Linux. Same error message as before. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I would revalidate your Linux environment.  I was able to run your code under both Mac OS/X and Ubuntu 14.04 in both Tomcat 8.0.x and 8.5.4.  I used a javax.ws.rs.core.Application configuration as you didn't include your web.xml but other than that it is your code directly.  I agree with @Andreas that you've got a bit of a mix of library versions but I don't know why you're running across this.  Do you have anything else deployed to the Linux Tomcat?  Have you made any modifications to, for example, the "lib" directory under the Tomcat installation?

Comment: Thank you for your analysis and thoughts. I added my `web.xml`. I didn't deploy anything else to tomcat, it is a fresh installation. I will try to line-up the versions of the libs ...

Answer (score -1):

The pom marks javax.servlet as provided so your app would use the version provided by Tomcat.  Based on the Exception Report it appears Tomcat on Linux is using an older version, where the getProperties() method does not exist.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getProperties--), the getProperties() method was added in 2.0 so Linux Tomcat is apparently using an older version.

Comment: `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` is not from `servlet-api`. Also, OP already said that both Windows and Linux are running Tomcat 8.5.4.

Comment: @Andreas - yes - bad assumption on my part.  Even though it's the same Tomcat version there's still a version mismatch.